# Probability of pulling 2 black and 1 red ball among 5 black, 5 white, and 5 red balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 5 black, 5 red, and 5 white balls. 3 balls are chosen without
replacement at random. We are asked to find the probability of getting 2 black and 1 red ball.

One way to solve it: $\frac{\binom{5}{2}*\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{15}{3}}  \approx 0.109$

Another way is to use conditional probability. We have:

P(2 black $\cap$ 1 red) = P(2 black | 1 red) * P(1 red) = $\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}} * \frac{5}{15} \approx 0.036$. Where did I forget to multiply by 3? What did I do wrong? I feel stupid

Comment: You correctly computed the probability that the first ball is red and the next two black, but that is only $\frac 13$ of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

In drawing without replacement, the question could ask for

(i) drawing in a specific order, eg $BBR$
(ii) drawing in all possible orders, viz $BBR,\;BRB,\; RBB$

For (i) it is easier to use the **general** multiplication rule (with implied conditional probabilities) as $\frac5{15}\frac4{14}\frac5{13}$

For (ii) it is easier to use the **choose** route, viz $\large\frac{\binom52\binom51}{\binom{15}3}$

Since a particular order has not been specified, it is implied that all possible orders need to be considered, and the **choose** route is easiest.

If instead you decide to use the general multiplication route, you need to have a multiplier, thus  $\binom31\times \frac5{15}\frac4{14}\frac5{13}$
because the single red ball could be at any of the three positions.

On the other hand, if a specific $BBR$ order had been specified and you want to use the **choose** route, you will need to **divide** by $\binom31$

Beginners often forget this, so be careful,
and as a general practice, use the simpler route without multiplier/divider depending on what has been asked.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is the event 2 black balls and 1 red ball in a sample of 3 balls from the specified urn without replacement. You want $\text{Pr}(X)$.

You might think in 2 ways: (i) sample 3 balls at the same time or (ii) sample each one of the 3 balls in order. From the stand point of the experiment the probability won't change.

Let us think using method (ii): $X=(R,B,B)\cup (B,R,B) \cup (B,B,R)$. Remember that in the sequence notation $(R,B,B)$ order is relevant, this is the sequence in which $R$ is the first ball, $B$ is the second and $B$ the third.

As these events are disjoint,

$$\Pr(X)=\text{Pr}((R,B,B))+\text{Pr}((B,R,B))+\text{Pr}((B,B,R))\ \ \ 
 (1)$$

When you computed $$\text{Pr}(2\ blacks\cap 1\ red)=\text{Pr}(2\ blacks|1\ red)\text{Pr}(1\ red)=\frac{10}{21\cdot 13}\approx 0.037$$ you've found only $\text{Pr}((R,B,B))$ in expression $(1)$ instead of
$$\text{Pr}(X)=\frac{10}{21\cdot 13}+\frac{10}{21\cdot 13}+\frac{10}{21\cdot 13}\approx 0.110$$